# Google Analytics report data using v3 with .NET randomly stopped working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-analytics-api, google-api-client

I have been using the code bellow on two different web applications on two different servers for months and they both randomly stopped working this week with a 400 bad request "An exception of type 'DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException' occurred in Google.Apis.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response."

```
            //Retreive total hits and hits in last 30 days from google analytic

            //This is the API url which we're storing to a string
            string scope = AnalyticsService.Scopes.AnalyticsReadonly.GetStringValue();

            //For whatever reason, this is labelled wrong. It is the email address
            //that you have added as a user to your Analytics account
            string clientId = "*******@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

            //This is the physical path to the file we downloaded earlier
            //To demonstrate this, I've kept the full path to my key file.
            //Obviously, you will need to change this to match where you've
            //stored yours.
            string keyFile = @"C:\key\*******.p12";

            //The password Google gives you, probably the same as the one below
            string keyPassword = "notasecret";

            //Store the authentication description
            AuthorizationServerDescription desc = GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description;

            //Create a certificate object to use when authenticating
            X509Certificate2 key = new X509Certificate2(keyFile, keyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            //Now, we will log in and authenticate, passing in the description
            //and key from above, then setting the accountId and scope
            AssertionFlowClient client = new AssertionFlowClient(desc, key)
            {
                ServiceAccountId = clientId,
                Scope = scope
            };

            //Finally, complete the authentication process
            //NOTE: This is the first change from the update above
            OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient> auth =
                new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(client, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);

            //First, create a new service object
            //NOTE: this is the second change from the update
            //above. Thanks to James for pointing this out
            AnalyticsService gas = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { Authenticator = auth });

            //Create our query
            //The Data.Ga.Get needs the parameters:
            //Analytics account id, starting with ga:
            //Start date in format YYYY-MM-DD
            //End date in format YYYY-MM-DD
            //A string specifying the metrics

            DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest r =
                gas.Data.Ga.Get(googleID, "2005-01-01", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "ga:totalEvents");


            //Specify some addition query parameters
            r.Filters = "ga:eventCategory==appStart;ga:eventAction==user";

            //Execute and fetch the results of our query

            GaData d = r.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

It randomly started working again on both applications on both servers without me changing anything.